# How to create dir on interenal storage if external is unavailable

Tags: android

I am creating a DIR from my app when app first time run.Here is the code for this

```
 if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        Log.d("MyApp", "No SDCARD");
} else {
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyContactsBackUp");
    directory.mkdirs();
}
```

now what i want to know is that if external storage is missing then how can i create DIR on internal storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In below code you can create directory structure in internal storage:-

```
File fil = new File(Activitythis.getFilesDir().getPath());
```